# Creating two separate instances from the same class causes them to be linked together?

Tags: pointers, dynamic, class, new-operator, instantiation

The problem I am having is I create two different menus from a single class. When I finish the first one, everything is fine. However when I create the second one and set it's region, it modifies the previous one as well. When I call Display() which just flips a boolean variable, it flips it for both instead of just the one I'm calling to.

```
cMenu* gameMenu;
cMenu* spellMenu;

  gameMenu = new cMenu();
 for(int i=0; i< 25; i++)
  gameMenu->AddButton("test", i);
 AddGameObject(gameMenu);

 spellMenu = new cMenu();
 spellMenu->SetRegion(580, 50, 52, 250, FORMAT_5X1); // This modifies gameMenu as well
 spellMenu->Display(); // So does this
 g.AddGameObject(spellMenu);
```

Comment: You use g.AddGameObject for spellMenu but just use the method for gameMenu not the method on the g object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect that the class cMenu has member variables that are static: thus there is only one copy of the data in memory and when you change it for spellMenu, it is changed also for gameMenu.

Do you have access to the code for cMenu?  If so, you could look at the variables modified inside cMenu::SetRegion().  Are any of those variables' definitions static?  If so, there's your problem.